# What is required for casting shadows in JavaFX 8 3D?

Tags: java, 3d, shadows

In a scene with an added point light the shapes are not casting shadows on each other. Is anything required to cause them to cast shadows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in the latest distribution of JavaFX that would suggest a 3D shadow middleware being incorporated in Java3D. See here for the [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/). The DropShadow classes are unrelated.

Java3D is not in the business of implementing game/model engine implementations for you.
Light and shadows are among the most complex topics in 3D graphics programming, and the chosen algorithm should meet your task requirement.

[Here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-create-the-shadow.html) would be a code-start for the absolute simplest of cases.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is quote from Oracle: "See the JavaFX 8 API documentation for more information." [Getting Started with JavaFX 3D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/subscene.htm#) Is it inaccurate?

Comment: Interesting, I saw that mentioned in the JavaOne 2013 Conference. But that is very recent -i.e. only weeks ago. Still, please provide me with a link that made you think that 3D shadows are an inclusive feature?

Comment: I never said I had such a link...

Comment: Then please consider accepting this unfortunate situation / answer and in doing so move towards a middleware. My (aged) bookmark http://games-middleware.dev.java.net/ unfortunately doesn't seem to work anymore? Good luck.